# Java Applet and ServiceLoader

Tags: java, jar, applet, noclassdeffounderror, serviceloader

Java Applet doesn't load service classes from someJar.jar!/META-INF/services/ by default causing NoClassDefFoundError exception.

How to make it work?

Comment: It should be using the thread context class loader which should default to being your applets class loader. You should be able to do `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` which should give the same as `this.getClass().getClassLoader()`. Can you read the resources as normal resources? (In any case, service loader is Satanic and should be burnt.)

Comment: yes, they are same. Not sure if I can read, will try

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps by using codebase_lookup property of applet?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/special_attributes.html

The above also implies that your services are either bundled in your applet jar, or you have also specified "codebase"

Comment: That's for loading loose class files (outside of zips/jars), which [typically] defaults to being on anyway.